# How to ensure resources are released using Google Dagger 2

Tags: java, dependency-injection, scope, dagger, dagger-2

[Google Dagger 2](http://google.github.io/dagger/) is all about object scopes e.g. when you need objects just during an http request you annotate your provider methods with `@RequestScope`.

But some provided resources need to be released for example a [CloseableHttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html) needs to be [closed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close--) or an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) needs to be [shutdown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--).

How can I specify which actions have to be taken in order to release an object when it goes out of scope using Google Dagger 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I specify which actions have to be taken in order to release an object when it goes out of scope using Google Dagger 2?

You can't. Dagger 2 is about providing dependencies to create your objects, not about managing them.

If you have objects that need to be stopped or shut down you will still have to use your components life cycle methods—like activities `onDestroy`—to do so.

Comment: But then what's the scoping about? Doesn't a non global scope imply that the scope will end? Nevertheless I get the part about *Dagger is about managing dependencies, not object lifetimes*

Comment: @ooxi Scopes are to group things that go together. You might have one `@Singleton AccountManager` but every user would get their own `@PerUser Balance`. Scopes help to ensure that objects with the same lifetime end in the same component and that nothing that changes less often depends on them, since the user might change more frequently than some singleton (which should not change).

Comment: Thank's for the clarification!